# How to show widememo column?

Tags: oracle

I'm searching some informations in my DB of my ETL(GENIO) and I'm kinda lost.
I would like to know if they're a way to remplace/show the value of a column with "(WIDEMEMO)" ? And also what is-it?

Thx in advice

[image: Example]

Comment: Which client is the screenshot from? That will determine how (and whether) you can expand the `widememo` - which just means its a large field, e.g. long, CLOB or a varchar over a certain size - to show all or some of the text it represents.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `WIDEMEMO` data type in Oracle.

Comment: Then [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7659576/266304). I think you can just click on a field to see the actual contents, too. I don't have Toad to verify though. The client is just labelling the data it's hiding as `widememo`; it may be one of several underlying real data types.

Comment: Thx Alex! I fell a bit stupid know cause yes by clicking on it you see the content.. And got m solution : " View => Toad Options => Data Grids => Data => [x] Preview CLOB and LONG data "

Answer (score 10):

The `(WIDEMEMO)` label is hiding `LONG` or `CLOB` data (or potentially a field defined a `VARCHAR2` with a high maximum size - some clients do that but I don't think Toad does).

You can click on the a hidden value to see the actual data within. [And as noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7659576/266304), you can turn on the preview from Toad's menus:

> View => Toad Options => Data Grids => Data => [x] Preview CLOB and LONG data

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect from putty and see. It will give the invisible column and the underlying columns on which it has been built.

I had a similar problem when Toad was showing WIDEMEMO, but when i tried from Putty it showed me the underlying columns as show below

eg:

```
SQL> select column_name, data_default, hidden_column   from   dba_tab_cols where column_name='SYS_STSV3T25IIMSBK3RLDOCESQVID';

COLUMN_NAME                                                                                                                      DATA_DEFAULT                                                                     HID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---
SYS_STSV3T25IIMSBK3RLDOCESQVID                                                                                                   SYS_OP_COMBINED_HASH("KT_NUM","SRAM_ATS_NUM")                                    YES
```

Comment: That isn't anything to do with PuTTY per se. You're using SQL\*Plus, which is a completely different client to Toad, and handles long/LOB columns differently. Incidentally, you might still need to look into the `set long` and `set longchunk` settings to show full values.